# jQuery extracting part of a ul tree

Tags: jquery, html-lists

Can anybody explain why I'm getting this. What I'm trying to do is replicate part of a `<ul>` list tree into another `<div>` based on matching an `<a>` link within the `<li>`.

It kind of works, in that it locates the correct part of the `<ul>` tree. But instead of replicating it, it seems to extract it totally from the original tree.

This is the code, but see the working thing at the link below:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  var test = "/our-services/";
  var subNav = $('#mainNav ul').find('a[href$="' + test + '"]').parent();
  $('#thing').html(subNav).wrapInner('<ul/>');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zt4TM/)

What gives?

Comment: You should probably be using [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) on `subNav` -- in your example, `subNav` IS the part of the tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `clone()` method to avoid moving the originally-found node/elements:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var test = "/our-services/"
        subNav = $('#mainNav ul').find('a[href$="' + test + '"]').parent().clone(true);

    $('#thing').html(subNav).wrapInner('<ul/>');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zt4TM/3/).

Or, slightly re-written:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var test = "/our-services/",
        subNav = $('#mainNav ul').find('a[href$="' + test + '"]').parent().clone(true);

    subNav.appendTo('#thing').wrap('<ul />');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zt4TM/2/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: Just about post the same, XD. You can just use $('#thing').html(subNav.clone()).wrapInner('<ul/>'); http://jsfiddle.net/zt4TM/4/

Answer (score 1):

Interesting behaviour! It's probably happening because jQuery is doing some strange stuff under the hood as it expects a `string` to be passed to the `.html()` method, but you are passing it an entire dom node wrapped in a jQuery object. See [the Jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Try getting the html contents of that node and pass that to the `.html()` method like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  var test = "/our-services/";
  var subNav = $('#mainNav ul').find('a[href$="' + test + '"]').parent();
  $('#thing').html(subNav.html()).wrapInner('<ul/>');
});
```

#### Edit

Remember that **this will strip any data or event handlers** that are attached to the original node, which may or may not be the required behaviour depending on your implementation. If you want to keep them, then use the `clone()` method as described in the other answer but use `clone(true)` instead of `clone(false)` which is the default.

#### See also:

[Passing an element or object to the jQuery .html() method](http://jamesallardice.com/passing-an-element-or-object-to-the-jquery-html-method/) for an explanation of why the .html() method accepts the jQuery object as well as a string.